# Link converting pregmatch working with markdown

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, preg-replace, markdown

```
function makeLinks($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('%(?<!href=")(((f|ht){1}(tp://|tps://))[-a-zA-^Z0-9@:\%_\+.~#?&//=]+)%i',
    '<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('%([:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:\%_\+.~#?&//=]+)%i',
    '\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);

        return $text;
}
```

It misses if I have something like this: `- www.website.org` (a hyphen then a space) at the beginning of a line. If I have - www.website.org - www.website.org it catches the second one.

Shouldn't that be covered by the space in the second `preg_replace`?

I also tried `%(\s\n\r(){})`

I am running it through markdown, but not till after (`markdown(makeLinks($foo))`) so I thought that shouldn't interfere, but when I take the markdown off and everything just echos out in one line, it does make links out of them.  If i put `makeLinks(markdown($foo))` it behaves the same as initially.. not making links out of the ones that begin with www at the beginning of list items.

Comment: Isn't `([[:space:]()[{}])` malformed, with a missing `]`?

Comment: i did try adding corresponding ] to end character class right before that `)` but it didn't actually change the result..

Comment: So you changed it to `([[:space]()[{}]])`? Rather hideous... What's the point of the `()` and `[{}]` in there, then, if the whole thing is a character class?

Comment: sorry.. i should have mentioned i tried several other combinations, removing the overall char class.. or all of them except around the space (which is necessary, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Thats some pretty dodgy regex work there. Here is a regex I would recommend instead for URL dectection:

```
%(?<!href="?)(((f|ht)(tp://|tps://))?[a-zA-Z0-9-].[-a-zA-^Z0-9@:\%_\+.~#?&//=]+)%i
```

Should be a lot more reliable than the two you have now.

Comment: i know it's dodgy... yours looks cleaner than what I have for sure, but it's still not performing any better.. it's still leaving the ones at beginnings of lines

Comment: Can you provide some test data to run against?